# how to calculate percent score (in semester)

Tags: statistics, average, percentages

Consider below data set. it has $14$ rows. Col $1$ indicates week number. Col $2$ is marks obtained, col $3$ is total marks and col $4$ indicates percentage.

What is correct indicator of score $\%$

1) Average of $14$ week percentage or

2) $\frac{\text{Total obtained}}{\text{Total score}} \times 100$

Please suggest. Below is the picture of dataset:

[image: Picture of Score obtained each week]

```
No  Obtained    Total   % 
1   12  12  100
2   13  14  92.85714286
3   12  12  100
4   10  11  90.90909091
5   9   10  90
6   6   7   85.71428571
7   7   7   100
8   9   10  90
9   12  12  100
10  10  10  100
11  6   8   75
12  7   7   100
13  8   8   100
14  8   8   100
    129 136 
    Total obtained  Total   

    % obtained  94.85294118 
    Average of each week        94.60575139
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think that each week is equally important regardless of the number of question, then use the first formula, that is you can just average out the weakly score.

If you believe that each question is equally important, then you should use the second formula.